# Control raspbmc via command line

Tags: raspbmc, ssh, terminal

I'm looking for a way to control raspbmc via command line through ssh.

Are there commands which let me "play music/video file", "pause", "stop" and give me access to addons?

Answer (score 2):

Raspbmc has a web interface, once you configure access to this within Raspbmc you can write a simple script to automate it using Perl or Python. Just replicate the HTTP transactions for the desired actions.